# Trying to run PHP script from command line (possible path issue)

Tags: php, windows, command-line, path, wampserver

I'm trying to run a PHP script from command line but I get an error telling me the system is looking for PHP in C:\php7\ but PHP is actually in C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.4

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: C:\php7\ext\bz2) (The specified module cannot be found.), C:\php7\ext\php_bz2.dll (The specified module cannot be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

I get the same warning for EVERY module

I've changed the path as directed here ([Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)) but it seems to just keep looking for it in the other directory.

I've restarted all processes, the problem persists. I've rebooted, the problem persists. Any ideas?

Additionally, when I type PATH into command line, the correct path C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.4 is returned in the list of paths and C:\php7 is not

Comment: Where is the `php.ini` file?

Comment: Just for curiosity, is there actually a php.exe in c:\php7? As far as I understand it, the path variable is used UNTIL the unknown program is found. If C:\php7 contains a php.exe then that will get used if it is found before the wamp path

Comment: @Felippe Duarte the php.ini file is in C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.4

Comment: @Jelmergu There is no C:\php7 directory, it does not exist.

Comment: Then remove it from the Windows PATH

Comment: In WAMPServer you should NEVER add the php folder to the Windows PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was inside the php.ini file.

I changed 
extension_dir ="c:/php7/ext/"
to
extension_dir ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/"